# Compact way to assign values by slicing list in Python

Tags: python, list, slice

I have the following list

```
bar = ['a','b','c','x','y','z']
```

What I want to do is to assign 1st, 4th and 5th values of `bar` into `v1,v2,v3`,
is there a more compact way to do than this:

```
v1, v2, v3 = [bar[0], bar[3], bar[4]]
```

Because in Perl you can do something like this:

```
my($v1, $v2, $v3) = @bar[0,3,4];
```

Comment: for `explicit is better than implicit`, you should try to avoid uses like this: how do your reader figure what's stored at other indices? why are these indices important?. Perhaps `collections.namedtuple` is better than a list of anonymous elements.

Comment: 'Coz in Perl you can do something like this:' thats why i feel perl has better data operations!

Comment: `for i in range(3): vars()[['v1', 'v2', 'v3'][i]] = ['a','b','c','x','y','z'][[0, 3, 4][i]]` do I win?

Comment: your exact code I will write as `v1, v2, v3 = bar[0], bar[3], bar[4]`, no need of parenthesis `[` `]` rhs expression.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> bar = ['a','b','c','x','y','z']
>>> itemgetter(0, 3, 4)(bar)
('a', 'x', 'y')
```

So for your example you would do the following:

```
>>> v1, v2, v3 = itemgetter(0, 3, 4)(bar)
```

Comment: `from operator import itemgetter as ig` for short.

Comment: @ashwch Just for confirmation - wouldn't it be better to use v1, v2, v3 = bar[0], bar[3], bar[4] instead of using an extra module(here operator) to solve it?

Comment: @Workonphp Indeed, if the indices are always fixed and all we want to do is assignment to some small number of variables. But in case the indices are being generated dynamically and the number of items needs to fetched are huge then `itemgetter` is really fast(in Pure only, numpy will beat Python though).

Answer (score 44):

Assuming that your indices are neither dynamic nor too large, I'd go with

```
bar = ['a','b','c','x','y','z']
v1, _, _, v2, v3, _ = bar
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. To be precise, it should be `v1, _, _, v2, v3, _` since the question was for indices 0, 3 and 4.

Comment: Yup, this is really the most idiomatic way in my opinion, itemgetter just seems like over complicating.

Answer (score 35):

Since you want compactness, you can do it something as follows:

```
indices = (0,3,4)
v1, v2, v3 = [bar[i] for i in indices]

>>> print v1,v2,v3     #or print(v1,v2,v3) for python 3.x
a x y
```

Comment: by using square brackets you are creating an extra temporary list, use parentheses to leave generator as is: `(bar[i] for i in indices)`

Comment: @user3075942, That is what I had earlier however when I ran it lots of time the `list` times were lower.

Comment: Sorry, I meant faster.

Comment: I've tested and must admit that for current implementation of CPython it's true. Probably because the list is short.

Comment: Though I don't think that a detail of a language implementation should influence the choice of approach.

Comment: @sshashank124 Read this blog [From List Comprehensions to Generator Expressions](http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html) It says: **"** Generator expressions are implemented using generators, whose execution requires a separate execution frame. Thus, generator expressions (especially if they iterate over a short sequence) were less efficient than list comprehensions. **"**

Comment: Sorry I means to respond  @user3075942

Comment: @Grijesh Thanks for the link. Although worth mentioning that your quote refers only to CPython 2.x

Comment: You could save memory by making indices a tuple, i.e. `(0,3,4)`. But generators are going to be less efficient in this case because of the small amount of data and the overhead of using a generator.

Comment: @sshashank124 infact you can avoid `(`  `)`, just write as  `indices = 0, 3, 4` --  and use spaces after `,`, `;`, `:` in coding.

Answer (score 21):

In `numpy`, you can index an array [with another array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) that contains indices. This allows for very compact syntax, exactly as you want:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: bar = np.array(['a','b','c','x','y','z'])
In [3]: v1, v2, v3 = bar[[0, 3, 4]]
In [4]: print v1, v2, v3
a x y
```

Using numpy is most probably overkill for your simple case. I just mention it for completeness, in case you need to do the same with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another method:

```
from itertools import compress

bar = ['a','b','c','x','y','z']
v1, v2, v3 = compress(bar, (1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0))
```

In addition, you can ignore length of the list and skip zeros at the end of selectors:

```
v1, v2, v3 = compress(bar, (1, 0, 0, 1, 1,))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress

Comment: Does this have any advantages over `itemgetter` or any other approach?

Comment: If indexes are represented as some sort of bitmask instead of direct numbers, "compress" will be simpler solution. For example, if they have been calculated this way: `(is_index_needed(x) for x in data_related_with_bar)`

Comment: It would be elegant, but in what way will it be simpler? Fewer accesses to bar, or less computation for mask? Like: `def unpack_bitmask(x): while (x>0): ...   yield x & 0b1 ...   x >>= 1`

Comment: Yes, I talk about code simplicity because topic about it.
Acces by direct index takes O(1) in normal list. Therefore, getting elements by several indexes will be faster then one iteration. But besides this, there are another cases. e.g. if you use deque, which takes O(n) getting element by index, you can get advantage in performance.
And yes, no computation for mask is needed.