# how to extract numbers from each position of a python list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list :

```
N=[[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]
```

How do i get it so use ths list to get another list with each list item being a number for each positon of the list items in `N` so that the new list looks like:

```
newList=[[0,0,0], [3,1,3],  [4,2] ,[9], [3]]
```

so he first item in newList is a sublist that contains the first number in N[0], the first number in N[1], and the first number in N[2]. The next sublist in N will do the same just for the second positions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756632/compact-way-to-assign-values-by-slicing-list-in-python

Comment: I don't understand the correspondence between your first list and your second list. Possibly I'm being thrown off by `4.2`, or possibly I just don't get it.

Comment: Same here. Could you clarify how you get `newList` using `N` please.

Comment: He wants to 'rotate' the lists as I understand the question, if that's the right way to describe it?

Comment: Description along with input/output seems clear: first list in output contains all of the first elements from each list in the input, second list contains all of the second elements, ... out-of-bounds are treated as nulls and not included

Comment: Exactly. And hence `4.2` is a typo and should be `4,2`. I edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Could make use of `izip_longest`, then filter out the default values, eg:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

N=[[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]   
new_list = [[el for el in items if el is not None] for items in izip_longest(*N)]
# [[0, 0, 0], [3, 1, 3], [4, 2], [9], [3]]
```

Comment: `filter(lambda x: x is not None, items)` is an alternative to comprehension, but I don't think it makes difference enough to deserver seperate answer ;)

Comment: @m.wasowski Yup - it'd probably work - just a couple of points though. 1) `filter` in Python 3.x will return an iterable and not a `list` and 2) it introduces the overhead of a function call where as `if el is not None` in a list-comp doesn't... If sticking with Python 2.x, you could also avoid the import and abuse `map(None, *N)` and then filter out - but that won't work in Python 3 as `None` is no longer allowed as the function argument...

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that there is no call overhead for lambda in such situation, that lambda code gets 'inlined' if not bound to any name, but used in functional calls like here.

Answer (score 1):

Try the list comprehension

```
newList= [reduce(lambda x,y: x + [y[i]] if i<len(y) else x, N, [])
          for i in range(max(map(len,N)))]
```

The `for` just iterates `i` upto the length of the longest sublist in `N`, using `map` with `len` to construct a temporary list of the lengths of the lists in `N` to calculate the `max` length.

The `reduce` builds up each sublist in the result by picking out the `i`th element of the corresponding input sublist -- but only if that sublist is long enough.

Answer (score 0):

A weird and inneficient way (but maybe easy to understand would be):

- Get maximum length of the lists in N
- Iterate all those lists from 0 to that maximum.
- If you got an error, that's because your original list (the one that came from N) doesn't have that item

---

```
N=[[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]
newList = []

max_items = max([len(lst) for lst in N])
for n_lst in N:
    for i in range(max_items):
        if len(newList) <= i:
            newList.append([])
        try:
            newList[i].append(n_lst[i])
        except IndexError:
            pass

print "new List: %s" % newList
```

Another approach, that maybe makes the code cleaner is initializing newList to a list with 5 items, since the longest list on your matrix N (`[0,1,2,9,3]`) has 5 elements. That way you know that your result (the `newList` variable) is going to have 5 lists:

```
N=[[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]
newList = []

max_items = max([len(lst) for lst in N])
newList=list([] for _ in range(max_items))

for i in range(max_items):
    for n_lst in N:
        if len(n_lst) > i:
          newList[i].append(n_lst[i])
print "new List: %s" % newList
```

Note that instead of catching an `IndexException`, you can also check if the `len()` of the list you're evaluating is `> i`

**EDIT**:

Just saw John Clements response (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901233/289011) which is by far the cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
# original list
N = [[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]

# create a new list of `n` lists (n being the length of the longest sublist in N)
newList = [[] for i in xrange(max([len(l) for l in N]))]

# iterate over each list
# enumerate - use the index to append into correct target list
for l in N:
    for i, val in enumerate(l):
        newList[i].append(val)

print newList
```

Yields:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [3, 1, 3], [4, 2], [9], [3]]
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Just to note that answers get jiggled about... so "it's similar to the above" probably isn't as useful as you'd like :)

Comment: Haha. No worries :) I just saw the others - as I expected, *far* more pythonic. I'm a Python noob so there's lots to learn in this question!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not use list comprehensions, but also does not require a pre-processing step to determine maximum list length.

```
N = [[0,3,4], [0,1,2,9,3], [0,3]]
newList = []

progress = True
i = 0;

while (progress):
    progress = False
    sublist = []

    for list in N:
        if len(list) <= i:
            continue
        else:
            sublist.append(list[i])
            progress = True

    if not progress:
        break

    newList.append(sublist)
    i = i+1

print(N)
print(newList)
```