# Assigning given values to elements of a list at given indices

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given some inputs

```
L=[0]*5

L1=[2,3]
L2=[12,13]
```

my required result is:

```
L=[0,0,12,13,0]
```

I know how to get this by "brute-force", but my question is, is there a "Pythonic" way to get it, e.g. with a list comprehension?

Comment: Do you need to support things like `L1 = [4, 2]`?

Comment: You might look at numpy to get fancy array indexing

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  What is the brute force method that does the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "brute-force"? Using a loop here is perfectly acceptable (and probably the only really readable option). You can always make it a function if you want to use it multiple times

Comment: Does L1 contain indexes according to L2 entries?

Comment: @user3421954 I've edited the title, and the body of your q to make the formatting a bit clearer. Please take a look at the edits and note that backquotes are for code: I've changed these to double quotes.

Comment: this question could be seen as the flip-side of [Compact way to assign values by slicing list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756632/compact-way-to-assign-values-by-slicing-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

L=np.zeros(5)
L1=np.array([2,3])
L2=np.array([12,13])

L[L1] = L2

print L
# array([  0.,   0.,  12.,  13.,   0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is enough pythonic for you:

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(L1):
...    L[j]=L2[i]
...
>>> L
[0, 0, 12, 13, 0]
```

and using list comprehension:

```
>>> [L[i] if i not in L1 else L2[L1.index(i)] for i in range(len(L))]
[0, 0, 12, 13, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very pythonic, but it *is* a list comprehension.

```
[l.__setitem__(i, l2.pop(0)) for i in l1]
```